# Why can't I connect to SQLServer uisng NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, tedious

I'm new using Node JS and now I'm creating a project that connects to SQL Server, but when I use the command `node Database\connect.js` It simply does do nothing, as it should do a console.log that it did connect or it didn't.

Here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "tedious": "^14.0.0"
  },
  "name": "weather-nodejs-apirest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "connect.js",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

And here is my `connect.js`

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var config = {
    server: 'SERVERNAME',
    authentication: {
        type: 'default',
        options: {
            userName: 'sa',
            password: 'password'
        }
    },
    options: {
        database: 'weather_app',
        // instanceName: 'Sqlexpress',
        rowCollectionOnDone: true,
        useColumnNames: false
    }
}

var connection = new Connection(config);
connection.on('connect', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Connected');
    }
});

module.exports = connection;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `connection.on(...)` method will not initiate the database connection itself. It only runs when the application initiates it using `connection.connect()` method.

Since you are exporting `connection` to the outside from `connect.js`, You should import and initiate the connection somewhere *(mostly in application entry point)*,

```
const connection = require('path/to/connect.js');

// initiate
connection.connect();
```

**Doc:** http://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/getting-started.html

Comment: It worked, now it says Connectionerror lol, thanks mate

Comment: Keep rocking... cheers